# How to prove the Cauchy distribution has no moments?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

How can I prove the Cauchy distribution has no moments?;

$$E(X^n)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^n}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx.$$

I can prove myself, letting $n=1$ or $n=2$ that it does not have any moment. However, I would I prove for ALL $n$, that the Cauchy distribution has no moments?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

For example, if $x>1$, then $$\int_1^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm d x\geq \int_1^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm d x.$$

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, let us write $f_n(x)$ for the expression in the integrand.

Of course for positive $n$, $\int_{-1}^{1}f_n(x)\;dx$ converges, so the problem is with the tails of the integral.

Now of course $x^{m}>x^n$ for $x>1$ for $m>n \geq 1$, so
$$I_m(R) \equiv\int_1^{R}f_m(x)\;dx \geq \int_1^{R}f_n(x)\;dx\equiv I_n(R)$$
You have shown that $I_1(R)$ diverges as $R\to\infty$, so necessarily so does $I_m(R)$ for $m > 1$.

A similar statement is true on $(-\infty,0]$, but you will have to take the sign into account.

Putting these together, you get your desired result.

Comment: For positive $n$ $\int_{-1}^{1}f_n(x)\;dx$, this integral equates to $0$ for even $n$ and a number for odd $n$. Therefore, it converges for all $n$. Correct? Also, how can I just say $I_1(R)$ diverges as $R\to\infty$, so necessarily so does $I_m(R)$ for $m > 1$? How can I be sure it diverges for $m>1$? Is there a rule or something I am missing?

Comment: Yes, the integrand is  just a bounded continuous function on $[-1,1]$, so you can put a bound on the integral by drawing a rectangle around the graph on that interval, and the area contained in the rectangle will be more than the area under the graph. For the other question, if $h(R) > g(R)$ and $g(R)$ diverges to infinity, then of course it will force $h(R)$ to diverge to infinity as well because $h$ is even larger than $g$.

Comment: So, by proving $I_1(R)$ diverges for $m=1$, then I can then say  $I_n(R)$ diverges for $n \geq 1$? Just be clear, as that seems like a big step.

Comment: It's just that "$I_n \geq I_1$" together with "$I_1\to\infty$" implies "$I_n\to\infty$", right?