# Showing MGF for Cauchy distribution does not exist

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, upper-lower-bounds, moment-generating-functions

As a part of independent research, I saw that the Cauchy distribution is a useful example of a case, where the characteristic function exists, but the mgf does not exist.

I wanted to show that for the Cauchy distribution, the MGF does not exist. To do this, I reasoned that
$$
\begin{split}
M(t) = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{tX}\right]
 &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{tx} dx}{\pi \left(1+x^2\right)} 
 \ge \frac{1}{\pi} \int_2^\infty \frac{e^{tx} dx}{1+x^2} 
 \ge \frac{1}{\pi} \int_2^\infty x^{-3} e^{tx} dx
\end{split}
$$
but I am having trouble showing the last integral diverges. Is this the right track, and if so, how do I complete the argument, or is there an easier way to do this?

I know that one can prove that all the moments don't exist (like in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3790780/16192)), but the problem is, that only shows derivatives at zero don't exist, not that the function does not. This is exactly what happens with the characteristic function -- it exists, and even is differentiable everywhere except at zero...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your integrals, I think $X$ should be $x$.  If $t>0$ then $x^{-3}e^{tx} \to \infty$ as $x$ increases, so the integral cannot converge.  For $t < 0$ perhaps you can look at $\int_{t=-\infty}^{-2}$

Comment: @Henry fixed thanks for advice and corrections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More simply, you can argue that the integrand is unbounded, because $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} \frac{e^{tx}}{1+x^2} = +\infty$ when $t>0$, while $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} \frac{e^{tx}}{1+x^2} = +\infty$ when $t<0$.

Nevertheless, the moment generating function exists at $t=0$, with $M_X(0) = \mathbb{E}[1] = 1$, in order to ensure that the Cauchy distribution is normalized.